# Publishing in powershell (filesystem) an ASP MVC 5 project to local IIS (TFS)

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, tfs-2015, msdeploy, webdeploy

I had to publish a web application with Team Foundation Server 2015.

**First i tried to make it with Team Foundation Server step** "copy file in target machine".

I gave these arguments to my Visual Studio Build Step :

```
/p:DeployDefaultTarget=Package 
/p:PackageAsSingleFile=true 
/p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true 
/p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem 
/p:DeleteExistingFiles=True 
/p:PackageLocation=$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\ic-drop
```

But, i only found DLL in my ic-drop folder, my web project was not here.

**So i decided to execute a powershell script to deploy my web application** (Asp MVC 4)

With this script:

```
# Define
$msbuild = "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe"
$options = "/p:PublishProfile='Default' /p:VisualStudioVersion=14.0  /p:AspnetMergePath='C:\Program` Files` (x86)\Microsoft` SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX` 4.6` Tools' /p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem /p:DeleteExistingFiles=True"
$proj = "'C:\Users\MyUser\Documents\Visual` Studio` 2015\Projects\Web\Web\Project.Path.Web.csproj'"

# Execute
$build = $msbuild + " $proj " + $options
Invoke-Expression $build
```

*PS : I created a publshing profile named "default"*

So, i tried to make the same action as the publishing command in Visual Studio:

[publishing in Visual Studio 2015](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNjwY.png)

To get in my destination folder theses files:

[Files deployed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qE9NN.png)

But my powershell just build my project and copy ouput files (dll) in my bin directory.

I think i missed something, but even after my search, i didn't found it...

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i missed one argument :

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true
```

It works as i expected now ! :)